# PostgreSQL Dependency variable addition to dockerfile Backstage

Tags: postgresql, backstage

I am trying to create a docker image through Backstage and deploy it using Heroku. The default DB in Backstage is SQLlite3, but I am using PostgreSQL in Heroku.Should I be using any PostgreSQL dependencies in the DOCKERFILE created by Backstage during the App creation. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHknM.png)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to install a postgres dependency. You only need to configure Postgres correctly in the app-config.yaml.

Comment: I see, but I am unable to connect my backend to the Database yet. I tried the "Backstage_plugin_Catalog" as database paramaeter. I keep getting this error, any suggestions ?? "Backend failed to start up, Error: Failed to connect to the database to make sure that 'backstage_plugin_catalog' exists, error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "116.15.61.141", user "ratyapoxegjukp", database "postgres", no encryption"

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever visited this [documentation](https://backstage.io/docs/tutorials/switching-sqlite-postgres#docsNav)?

In short:

1. You need to install postgresql as a dependency of your backend:

```bash
yarn add --cwd packages/backend pg
```

2. Perform the settings in app-config.yaml

```
backend:
  database:
-    client: better-sqlite3
-    connection: ':memory:'
+    # config options: https://node-postgres.com/api/client
+    client: pg
+    connection:
+      host: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
+      port: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
+      user: ${POSTGRES_USER}
+      password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
+      # https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl
+      # you can set the sslmode configuration option via the `PGSSLMODE` environment variable
+      # see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html Table 33.1. SSL Mode Descriptions (e.g. require)
+      # ssl:
+      #   ca: # if you have a CA file and want to verify it you can uncomment this section
+      #     $file: <file-path>/ca/server.crt
``
```